# Firebase priority is sometimes null even though I always insert with ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am getting a crash when I try to call `child.getPriority()` and cast it to a double on a child that should have definitely been inserted with a priority of `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.  In fact, I am all but certain that I never insert items without a priority, yet I'm still getting this crash.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
       at com.myapp.android.core.MyService$QueueListener.onDataChange(MyService.java:688)
       at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:42)
       at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
       at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Can you show a code snippet that throws this exception? Keep in mind that `onDataChange` may fire with a `null` value in the `DataSnapshot` initially.

Comment: This was happening in onDataChange, I bet that's what was happening.  I'm now only dealing with the data if child.getValue() is not null, hopefully that will prevent this.

Comment: Please consider including some code that reproduces these conditions. It's hard to guess at timing issues and coding errors without seeing the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Cheers.